# How to dynamically change content of the classin an Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to  **dynamically** change the class name when a `showPending` function called . I don't know how to achieve that through `angular js`.

```
<li data-match-route="pending" ng-class='menuactive'><a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="showPending()" >Pending</a></li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify what class should be applied with an expression, as explained in the docs; [AngularJS: API: ngClass](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)

```
<li data-match-route="pending"
    ng-class="{menuactive: expression}">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="showPending()" >Pending</a>
</li>
```

set `expression` in your controller in your showPending function, and the css class will be updated accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-class directive for that. In your function which is getting called set an expression named "value" as true or false, which you will use in ng-class as mentioned in following example.

```
    <li data-match-route="pending" ng-class="{menuactive:value}">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="showPending()" >Pending</a></li>
```

Comment: How is this different from the other answer?

Comment: I saw it late. Refresh issues. :)